# How i can to get previous and current value input in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

How i can to get previous and current value input  in lwc ?

```
<template>
<template for:each={options} for:it="it">
    <div key={it.value}>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" id={it.value} value={it.value} name={radioGroup} data-id={it.value} onclick={handleRadioClick}  />
            <span>{it.label}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about how/why you are looking for this?  There may be another way to get what you need

Comment: for example I have a picklist of 3 values, I want to recover the previous value of the picklist and the new one

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the previous value directly. This is a limitation of HTML, not LWC itself. You need to store that value somewhere. In the following example, we store the value in `#selectedValue`, and we can read the new value from `event.target.value`.

```
#selectedValue;
handleRadioClick(event) {
  const newValue = event.target.value;
  if(newValue != this.#selectedValue) {
    // Do something
  }
  this.#selectedValue = newValue;
}
```

Comment: I'm new to js and lwc, can you detail the function to retrieve the old selected value? THANKS

Comment: @Salem You cannot *retrieve* it, it is already gone. You need to *store* the old value first. The fourth line of this example shows how I'm comparing the new value to the old value.